# Array of Objects useState in React Typescript losing the first array element when triggering onChange on second array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following piece of code which is a snippet of the entire thing. Basically I am trying to  have a form, with the option of creating multiple entries of the same form on a button click. The aim is to store the data in an array of objects where each object represents one form.

The problem is that, although I am managing to create the second entry in the state that is defined in the parent component, when I try to enter text in the 2nd entry with `onChange`, the 1st entry is removed.

My guess is that I am doing something wrong in the logic of how I am trying to save the key events, but I cannot pinpoint it.

**Parent Component**

```
export interface IExperience {
    position: string,
    location: string, 
    startDate: string,
    endDate: string,
    description: string
}

const Experience = () => {
    let [preview,setPreview] = useState(false)
    let [data,setData] = useState<IExperience[]>([{position: '', location: '', startDate: '', endDate: '', description: ''}]) // Default state is not undefined
    let [button,setButton] = useState('Edit')

    return (
        <div className={styles.visitorContainer}>
            <Nav />
            {preview ? <Message setPreview={setPreview} data={data} setData={setData} /> : <Preview setPreview={setPreview} data={data} setData={setData} button={button} setButton={setButton}/>}
            <Foot />
        </div>
    )
}
 
export default Experience
```

Ignore the preview part as it is redundant for the problem I am facing.

**Child Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { ReactNode, useState } from 'react'
import { IExperience } from '.'
import { Preview } from './preview'

export const Message = ( { setPreview,data,setData }: {setPreview: any,data: IExperience[],setData: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IExperience[]>>} ) => {
    let [count,setCount] = useState(0)
    let formRows: ReactNode = []

    const formHandler = (i:number) => {
        console.log(data) //Console log here also shows data is undefined

        return formRows = [
             (<div key={`innerDiv${i}`}>
                <div><h2>Entry {i+1}</h2></div>
                <div>
                    <label>Position</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='Engineer' onChange={(e) => setData({...data,position: e.target.value})} value={data.position} /> //Error is here (data is undefined)
                </div>
            </div>)
         ]
    }

    const updateHandler = () => {
        setCount(prev => prev+1)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={(e) => sendData(e)}>
                    {[...Array(count+1)].map((d,i) => (<div key={`outerDiv${i}`} >{formHandler(i)}</div>))}
                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value='+' onClick={() => updateHandler()} />
                    </div>
        
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Again I am leaving out redundant stuff so that it stays focused on the problem.

I am not able to find a similar question to this, or a solution online

Hope this the code is clear :)

Comment: i guess you should check this `setData({...data,position: e.target.value})}`, in which you arent preserving the old array, but resetting it to only a single object. Try to map over the `data` array and change only the target item in the array based on the position.

Comment: The problem is with your state update function. In your child component change the stateupdate function implementation like below.

```setData(previousState => [ ...previousState, { position: e.target.value }]);```

Comment: None of the above solves it, `data` is an array of objects and I believe I have to access each element with the `[]` like so`setData(previousState => [ ...previousState[i], { position: e.target.value }])`, but this also gives an error.